# Eclipse PDT turn on Syntax highlighting for php files in svn repository exploring perspective

Tags: php, eclipse, svn, eclipse-pdt

I use eclipse pdt, eclipse helios sr2 (eclipse 3.6.2, pdt 2.2.1, subclipse 1.6.18, svn javahl 1.6.17 )

Syntax highlighting for php files works fin in php perspective, but in svn repository exploring perspective php files are not color coded.

xml files are color coded
diffs of php files from within svn are color coded

but double clicking on a php file to show the repository version just shows as a plain text files.

I can't find any option to change that effects this

*.php is registered under general > content types > text->php content type
*.php has associated editors "php editor", "text editory" under editors > file associations.
both are locked by php content type, php editor is default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a bug in pdt 2.2.1
[Bug 321332 - Eclipse PDT, Unsupported content type when opening PHP file from SVN](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=321332)

I installed eclipse indigo (3.7), pdt 3 , subclipse 1.6.18, data tool platforms
svn repository explorer provides syntax highlighting and works as it should